# how to define text alignment, alpha of text background and add image before text while adding text to photo

Tags: swift, photo

```
for (index, textData) in textDataCurrentImg.enumerated() {
                let textColor = textData.fontColor
                let textFont = UIFont(name: textData.font.fontName, size: textData.fontSize)!
                let padding: CGFloat = 10.0
                let breakdText = textData.addBreaks(in: textData.text, with: textFont, forWidth: newImage.size.width, padding: Int(textData.xPosition))
                
                let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImage.size, false, scale)
                
                // Draw image
                newImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: newImage.size))
                
                let textFontAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
                        NSAttributedString.Key.font: textFont,
                        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor,
                        ]
                
                if let backColor = textData.backColor {
                    // Draw background rectangle
                    let textSize = breakdText.size(withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
                    let backgroundRect = CGRect(
                        origin: CGPoint(x: textData.xPosition - padding, y: textData.yPosition - padding),
                        size: CGSize(width: textSize.width + 2 * padding, height: textSize.height + 2 * padding)
                    )
                    backColor.setFill()
                    UIRectFill(backgroundRect)
                }
                
                // Draw text on top of the background rectangle
                breakdText.draw(in: CGRect(x: textData.xPosition, y: textData.yPosition, width: newImage.size.width, height: newImage.size.height), withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
                
                newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() ?? image
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            }
```

this is my code and i am adding texts to photo here

text alignment - for text alignment i have tried this but not working as expected.

```
let textFontAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: textFont,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor,
        NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: {
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.alignment = textData.textAlignment
            return paragraphStyle
        }()
    ]
```

alpha of text background `let alpha: CGFloat = 0.5  let alphaColor = backColor.withAlphaComponent(alpha)`

add image before text - `if textData.isLocation` i want to add one image before text as below
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYKY9.png)

Comment: Have you tried to put all contents inside a view (image, transparent text, etc) into a UIView and then take a snapshot of that View? I believe it will be much easier.

Comment: @son yes i am putting these all into imageview but how to take snapShot of that imageview only ?

Comment: Glad I could help. You replied too fast haha, I've made an example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all the contents in a custom view like this:

[image]

Then you're able to hide any sub-views or the entire view you want before taking a snapshot

```swift
class CollectionPhoto: UIView {
  @IBOutlet private var pinIcon: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet private var contentLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet private var contentImage: UIImageView!
  
  func takeSnapShot() -> UIImage? {
    pinIcon.isHidden = true
    contentLabel.isHidden = true
    
    ...
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
     
    pinIcon.isHidden = false
    contentLabel.isHidden = false

    return image
  }
}
```